# Import text file collection into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to collect data from a text file in order to populate a table in Sql Server. The collection part is working but at "ExecuteNonQuery" I get the "No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List" error. I've researched this error here and at other sites and from what I can gather, the error is caused by trying to populate a table with an array or there is something wrong with my parameters. I've tried various adjustments to the code which populates the table. Haven't touch the collection code as I hate to fix what isn't broken. Here is my code:

```
var mbrNbr = new List<string>();
var sPages = new List<int>();
var ePages = new List<int>();
var startPage = 0;
var endPage = 0;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"\\path\textFile.txt"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() > 0)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        var memberNumber = line.Substring(698,11);
        var passThru = line.Substring(698,11);
        var oceMax = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(910, 3));
        if (passThru.Equals(memberNumber))
        {
            mbrNbr.Add(memberNumber);
            startPage = endPage + 1;
            endPage += oceMax * 2;
            ePages.Add(endPage);
            sPages.Add(startPage);

        }
    }
}

var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("server/db conneciton");
sqlConn.Open();

var updateSql = @"update myTable
                set MemberNbr = @memberNumber,
                StartPage = @startPage, EndPage = @endPage";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, sqlConn))
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberNumber", mbrNbr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startPage", sPages);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endPage", ePages);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

sqlConn.Close();
```

In an effort to construct a specific question, here goes: Does SQL Server not accept an array or is it a parameter issue or both?

Comment: A couple things your SQL is doing update?  That should be insert I beleive or else you need to add a where clause for a specific ID to update in your table.

The paramaters you have are LISTS, you can not pass lists to a SQL Command.

You can either do your SQL insert inside the loop of the file looping, and just assign each variable to a string and run your insert.  Or look into SQL TableTypes and create a tabeltype in SQL and create a C# object to hold all your data and then pass that to a SQL SP to insert all the data at once from the file.

Comment: (Table Type in SQL is basically equivalent to object in C#

Comment: You either need to loop and do each update individually or better yet, create a procedure that receives a table valued parameter that you can call with the entire collection.

Comment: Not sure how the stored procedure works but maybe you can use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) to turn the lists into a comma separated value string and pass those to the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Boy, I got a lot of learnding to do.

Comment: I ended up putting the SQL insert inside the loop and got it working.  Started reading about Table Types, SPs, and TVPs though.  Some good stuff.  Thanks everyone!